Which Forbidden PLMNs are present in the list retrieved by TelephonyManager.getForbiddenPlmns?
In a SIM, there are several lists used by the phone to know which network it has to try to register to.
The lists are updated when the mobile device tries to register under the mobile network of a foreign operator. If a mobile network is included in a list of forbidden networks, the mobile device doesn't try to register to that network.
Some not-exhaustive examples:

Forbidden PLMNs for GPRS service
5GS forbidden tracking areas for roaming
Forbidden tracking areas for roaming
Forbidden location areas for roaming
...

The list update is done on the basis of the answer the mobile device gets from the foreign network during the registration phase or after the registration through a message called OTA (Over the Air).
TelephonyManager provides a method to get the list of forbidden PLMNs (getForbiddenPlmns): is it a complete list of all the operators included in all the lists in the SIM (see list above), or is it only the list of Forbidden PLMNs for which the mobile phone received a Roaming not Allowed answer to the registration trial?
